# emulator not starting and giving some errors

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-5.0-lollipop

**I am Getting the error on the console**

```
I have just updated the AVD to 5.0 from 4.3
```

**Please help to resolve the error**

```
 [2014-11-18 10:49:21 - Emulator] ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them
    [2014-11-18 10:49:21 - Emulator]        you will have to do at least one of the following:
    [2014-11-18 10:49:21 - Emulator] 
    [2014-11-18 10:49:21 - Emulator]        - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
    [2014-11-18 10:49:21 - Emulator]        - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
    [2014-11-18 10:49:21 - Emulator] 
    [2014-11-18 10:49:21 - Emulator]        Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
    [2014-11-18 10:49:21 - Emulator]        aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
    [2014-11-18 10:49:21 - Emulator]        Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.
    [2014-11-18 10:49:21 - Emulator]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Go to the SDK Manager and Look at the installed 5.0 version and uninstall the images of api which are of 64bit** 
Only install the x86 type if your linux is of 32bit and vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you are apparently running on a 32bit system and the Android emulator is designed to operate best in a 64 bit environment. The only real solution is to install a 64bit operating system.

If your hardware doesn't support 64bit or you can't reinstall right now you can temporarily bypass the problem by passing -force-32bit when you start the emulator from the commandline or by setting ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to true in your environment (as the error says). You can do this by running:

gedit .profile
From a terminal. Add the text:

export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true
to the end of the file and save and close it. I can't test it right now but you'll either need to run source .profile from the terminal or restart for the changes to take effect.

Try launching the emulator.

It is highly recommended that you install a 64bit operating system to continue your Android development because Google will eventually remove the 32bit binaries which will cause your emulator to stop working. Android itself is also moving towards a x64 architecture, so by staying with 32bit you will get left behind very soon.

Here is the reference 
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/534044/error-32-bit-linux-android-emulator-binaries-are-deprecated-when-attemping-t](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534044/error-32-bit-linux-android-emulator-binaries-are-deprecated-when-attemping-to-r)o-r

Comment: but y this is happening i have just installed 5.0 through sdk manager and after that this error is occuring

Comment: seems that they have done something to 5.0 , above mentioned solution is for linux , u can google "How to Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment."